# Is there any way to list the functions and data structures available from the native interface in Raku?

Tags: raku, nativecall

Mainly with the objective of creating sensible examples, I'd like to know which data structures and functions are available for use in Raku's `native` interface, as in

```
class a-class is repr('CStruct') { has int $.whatever; }
class another-class is repr('CPPStruct') { has int $.whateverelse; }
sub a_native_function( another-class $object ) is native {*};
```

Is there some way of listing them? I'd like specially to obtain examples of C++ function and data structures, so that I don't have to create and compile an external library to create an example.